# Django update or create - pre save

Tags: django, django-orm

I am struggling with what may be a simple issue. I am trying to create a record or update if there is already an existing record in place. I am trying to override the models save function. The criteria is based on is there a user that already has an answer for their exp_type. I wanted to update it if so, if not then i want to create it.

Here is what i have:

```
class UserExperienceTypeAnswer(TimeStampedModel):
    NA, NONE, SOME, LOTS, EXPERT = range(5)
    ANSWER_CHOICES = {
        (NA, "Not interested"),
        (NONE, "None"),
        (SOME, "Some"),
        (LOTS, "Lots"),
        (EXPERT, "Expert"),
    }

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    exp_type = models.ForeignKey(
        RecruitmentExperienceType, models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False
    )
    answer = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=ANSWER_CHOICES, default=NONE, blank=False, null=False
    )

    unique_together = ["user", "exp_type"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        record = UserExperienceTypeAnswer.objects.filter(
            user=self.user, exp_type=self.exp_type
        ).first()

        if not record:
            super(UserExperienceTypeAnswer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            //This is the part im unsure of. I tried to save the record from query above
            record.answer = self.answer
            super(UserExperienceTypeAnswer, record).save(*args, **kwargs)
            // This gives duplicate key error (which i assume is because its trying to create new record)
           
            // I also tried to create model directly but this creates recursion error (as i assume i am calling this method on save in infinate loop. 
            UserExperienceTypeAnswer.objects.create(
                 user=self.user, exp_type=self.exp_type, answer=self.answer
            )
```

Edit: In case question is not clear.

I want to create a new record if record does not exist based on exp_type and user filter. If it does exist, then update and save that existing record with new answer.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to update existing record if it exists or create new record if it doesnt. Based on user and exp_type already existing as a record.

Comment: I would manage it in a view (or a dedicated model's method), I'm not sure it's necessary to override standard methods. In a view, when request is POST, test if record exist and react accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As per Christophes suggestion, I added this to viewset instead as below. Its a DRF view so I used the create function.

```
class UserExperienceTypeAnswerViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.UserExperienceTypeAnswer.objects.all().order_by("id")
    serializer_class = serializers.UserExperienceTypeAnswerSerializer

    filterset_fields = {
        "id": ("exact",),
        "user": ("exact",),
    }

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        record = models.UserExperienceTypeAnswer.objects.filter(
            user=request.data["user"], exp_type=request.data["exp_type"]
        ).first()

        if not record:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        else:
            record.answer = request.data["answer"]
            record.save()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(record)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```